# Send Data from chrome extension to Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have created a simple Chrome extension which stores all a few clicks on some Z webpage in my content_script. So, I want to know a way to send this data (json) to my node.js file (lets say /start).

How exactly to go about this? starting from sending data from the extension through ajax AND receiving this data in my /start router js file?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried every possible. But finally found a solution. Thanks anyway @bdkopen. Will post the solution soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, if anyone falls into the same hurdle.

Basically, I sent the data from my content_script (js file) to background (js file) of my extension through chrome runtime message. Now Background file must be defined in the manifest, and is basically a file which runs in the background.
From Here, I made a Web API call (XMLHttpRequest) from the background.js to my localhost server AND made it a POST function.

```
var xj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xj.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/log", true);
xj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xj.send(JSON.stringify({ action: <your data>}));
xj.onreadystatechange = function () { if (xj.readyState == 4) { console.log(xj.responseText); } }
```

Now, in my node.js index page, I capture the send request in a Post function

```
router.post('/log', function(req, res, next){
     console.log(req.body) //Your data from the extension
});
```

Comment: does that intermediary exchange mandatory  (passing the data from content_script to -> background)  ? or can I right away make the request from content_script

Comment: @emre-ozgun I've tried calling my Express server directly from contentScript. The problem is that '/api/myservice' endpoints are resolved with the hostname of the webpage you are visiting with the browser, not 'localhost'.