# Send data from chrome extension to website/web application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension, now I want to send some data from my extension to my website. I don't want to use backend as in this example: **[Send Data from chrome extension to Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026366/send-data-from-chrome-extension-to-node-js)**

I want some way I can get the data in my frontend, my website doesn't have a backend. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Inject a [content script](/q/4532236) and then send a DOM `CustomEvent` message to your page.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by wOxxOm by using content script as stated here: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236/how-to-access-the-webpage-dom-rather-than-the-extension-page-dom) we can access the DOM of our webpage and make changes and send data to it from our chrome extension.